# blob tracking in usb_cam?

Tags: usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I do blob tracking in usb_cam?

I loaded usb_cam package in the bosch_drivers, and followed Pharos test bed

http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Use_a_Webcam_in_ROS_with_the_usb_cam_Package

to try it out.  I got the video window OK!

I saw another cam package on Pharos mention blob tracking (launch looks similar).  Where is documentation on how to do blob tracking on usb_cam?

Thanks,
Alan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52247/blob-tracking-in-usb_cam?/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On which page on the pharos wiki you saw the blob tracking? The usb_cam outputs a video stream on /usb_cam/image_raw. You should change the blob tracker to look at this videostream.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on 2013-01-15**:
The page is: http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Detect_Blobs_using_ROS_Package_cmvision.  It's another package, cmvision.  Are these drivers, and another package (transport?) gets called to do the blob detection?  I didn't see cmvision example doing the blob detection, for that matte

**Comment by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on 2013-01-15**:
The page is: http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Detect_Blobs_using_ROS_Package_cmvision

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-01-15**:
You can just roslaunch that file and it will start your webcam and the blob tracking. Documentation is here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/cmvision